# Clear SD Card on Galaxy Tab 10.1 gt-p7510

Tags: sd-card

I know how to factory rest my tablet but all of the information on my sd card remains. Because the sd card isnt removable is there a way to wipe everything from it?

Comment: If the card was left untouched by a factory reset: could you please check in *Settings › Storage* and watch out whether there's a "format" or "wipe" option for it? My device has that only for the external card (internal SD obviously uses FUSE, sharing the partition with `/data` – yours might have a separate partition and thus have this option here).

Answer (score 0):

If you have no option to wipe internal SD card during factory reset you still can clear it manually with any kind of file explorer/manager you'll find at Play Store (navigate to your SD card, and delete all content there). Just make it before factory reset and you're done.

<sup>[credits: Izzy and our little conversation in the now deleted comments]</sup>